# Unable to use for loop to change which JLabel is currently being affected

Tags: java, for-loop, imageicon

I am attempting to use a forloop to be able to change which jlabel is being affected, as for they all perform the same function, and have the same name other than the numerical value at the end of each name.

Essentially, I use a drag and drop transfer handler to create a food web game. I want to randomize the game to three different food webs that may appear. The randomization is fine and all, but I am unknowledgable of how to use a loop to determine which JLabel's icon is being set. Since I am using generally all the same name for each individual JLabel that has an icon that will change based on which themed food web was randomly selected, **I am wanting to know how to make the loop change which JLabel is being selected, as for I get a syntax error from attempting to do the "selection(i+1)".**

```
private static int randomNumber(){
    return(int) (Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1) + 1);
}

private void generateQuiz(){
    switch(randomNumber()){
        case 1: //the for loop changes each available selection based on each element in the foor loop.
            for(int i = 0; i < consumers1.size(); i++){
                selection(i+1).setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
                        "/resources/quiz/"+consumers1.get(i)+".png")));
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            break;

        case 3:
            break;
```

want: change each of these selection boxes auto-magically using a for loop rather than typing each individual thing manually for each case
[image: my selection boxes]

**EDIT:** This is the rest of the general code around this problem,

```
private String[] producers = {"grass", "plankton", "berries"};
private ArrayList<String> consumers1 = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList<String> consumers2 = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList<String> consumers3 = new ArrayList();

//mouselistener to handle all image move-ability
MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseListener() { 

    @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {} 

    //a mouselistener for that each img has the ability to be moved into spots
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { 
        JComponent jc = (JComponent)e.getSource();
        TransferHandler th = jc.getTransferHandler();
        th.exportAsDrag(jc, e, TransferHandler.COPY);

       // System.out.println(producers1.getIcon());
    }

    @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
};

/**
 * Creates new form Quiz
 */
public Quiz() {
    initComponents();
    //sets the jframe to the center of the screen
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    //changes how the jframe closes
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                //confirm dialog to ensure user wants to close, if not return
                    int confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                        "A quiz is currently inprogress. "
                        + "\nAll unsubmitted quizs will not be saved!"
                        + "\nDo you wish to exit?",
                        "Exit", 
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
            }
    });

    //random algorithm; t1 = x, tn = (tn-1) + xn

    //<--- RANDOM QUIZ GENERATION --->
    //add all the image names to array lists
    Collections.addAll(consumers1, "goat", "rabbit", "jackal", "wildcat",
        "lion");
    Collections.addAll(consumers2, "fish", "mussel", "bird", "octopus",
            "human");
    Collections.addAll(consumers3, "butterfly", "grasshopper", "frog",
            "spider", "snake");
    generateQuiz();
    // end of quiz generaiton

    //<--- DRAG AND DROP ADDITIONS LISTENERS AND TRANSFER HANDLERS --->
    //adds mouse listener to be able to drag and drop the imgs in the seleciton boxes
    selection1.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
    selection2.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
    selection3.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
    selection4.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
    selection5.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
    selection6.addMouseListener(mouseListener);

   //creates transfer handlers to bea ble to drag and drop the images in the frame
    TransferHandler th = new TransferHandler("icon");
    selection1.setTransferHandler(th);
    selection2.setTransferHandler(th);
    selection3.setTransferHandler(th);
    selection4.setTransferHandler(th);
    selection5.setTransferHandler(th);
    selection6.setTransferHandler(th);

    producer.setTransferHandler(th);
    consumer1.setTransferHandler(th);
    consumer2.setTransferHandler(th);
    consumer3.setTransferHandler(th);
    consumer4.setTransferHandler(th);
    consumer5.setTransferHandler(th);
   //<--- END OF DRAG AND DROP ADDITIONS LISTENERS AND TRANSFER HANDLERS --->
}

private static int randomNumber(){
    return(int) (Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1) + 1);
}

private void generateQuiz(){
    switch(randomNumber()){
        case 1:
            for(int i = 0; i < consumers1.size(); i++){
                selection(i+1).setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
                        "/resources/quiz/"+consumers1.get(i)+".png")));
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            break;

        case 3:
            break;
    }
}
```

P.S.: It's made in netbeans gui builder for a school assignment so it'x declared in the automatic generated code by neatbeans

Comment: Show us the code where `selection` is being defined.  My guess is that you want to use either an array or some type of collection to store your `JLabel` labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, "selection..." is simply a variable name.

When the Java program is compiled, most variable names are replaced by pointers to memory locations, so you can't assemble a string at run time and invoke the corresponding variable. (You could make them public and use Reflection but it would be absolutely wrong here).

Here the simplest way to do what you are trying is the following:

```
JLabel[] selections={
    selection1,
    selection2,
    selection3,
    selection4,
    selection5,
    selection6
};
```

and then use `selections[i]` instead of `selection(i+1)`.